# Stop Qtimer in a slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer

I created a slot where a QTimer is started,
it must increase a variable and when it reaches certain value it must stop.
This is  code:

```
void MainWindow::on_start_clicked() {
    b = 95;
    m_timer->start(1000);
    if (b == 98) {
        m_timer->stop();
        return;
    };
}
```

---

```
m_timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(m_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(increase()));
```

---

```
void MainWindow::increase() {
    b += 1;
    qDebug() << b;
}
```

Comment: Can you stop the timer inside the increase slot is being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

To have the timer stop when triggered you can add the logic to the slot, this is what I would do, the slot would be:

```
void MainWindow::on_start_clicked() {
    b = 95;
    m_timer->start(1000);
}
```

The connection would be:

```
connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::increase);
```

*The above connection method is the Qt 5 way of making connections, it's a compile time check and will error out if the connection is not possible; so you don't need to wait till run time to make the check.

Finally, the slot would be:

```
void MainWindow::increase() {
    if(b >= 98) {
        b++;
        qDebug() << b;
        m_timer->start(1000);
    } else {
        //b has finally reached 98
        m_timer->stop();
    }
}
```

The above code will allow the timer to continue triggering every second until b has reached 98, once it reaches 98, it will trigger one last time. However, instead of increasing b by one, it will stop the timer indefinitely.